# VB program, looping for iterations and excel writing

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program for an internship and need some advice. I've done my research but have mostly returned fruitless... I need to loop the "buttonOneClick for one second iterations. The program will send a "P" character, wait one second, send a p, wait one second, etc... Also I need to write the information it receives to an excel spreadsheet. Any help/critiquing of existing code would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have:

```
Public Class Form2

Dim buttonOnePush As Boolean = False
Dim buttonTwoPush As Boolean = False



Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Send strings to a serial port.

    Using com5 As IO.Ports.SerialPort =
            My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM5")
        com5.WriteLine("P")

    End Using

End Sub

Function ReceiveSerialData() As String
    ' Receive strings from a serial port.
    Dim returnStr As String = ""

    Dim com5 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing
    Try
        com5 = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM5")
        com5.ReadTimeout = 10000
        Do
            Dim Incoming As String = com5.ReadLine()
            If Incoming Is Nothing Then
                Exit Do
            Else
                returnStr &= Incoming & vbCrLf
            End If
        Loop
    Catch ex As TimeoutException
        returnStr = "Error: Serial Port read timed out."
    Finally
        If com5 IsNot Nothing Then com5.Close()
    End Try

    Return returnStr
End Function


Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) AndAlso IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) Then
        TextBox1.Text = CDec(TextBox2.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox6_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox6.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(TextBox6.Text) AndAlso IsNumeric(TextBox3.Text) Then
        TextBox6.Text = CDec(TextBox3.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox7_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox7.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(TextBox7.Text) AndAlso IsNumeric(TextBox4.Text) Then
        TextBox7.Text = CDec(TextBox4.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox8_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox8.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(TextBox8.Text) AndAlso IsNumeric(TextBox5.Text) Then
        TextBox8.Text = CDec(TextBox5.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox15_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox15.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(TextBox15.Text) AndAlso IsNumeric(TextBox16.Text) Then
        TextBox15.Text = Hex(TextBox16.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox14_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox14.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(TextBox14.Text) AndAlso IsNumeric(TextBox11.Text) Then
        TextBox14.Text = Hex(TextBox11.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox13_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox13.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(TextBox13.Text) AndAlso IsNumeric(TextBox10.Text) Then
        TextBox13.Text = Hex(TextBox10.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox12_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox12.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(TextBox12.Text) AndAlso IsNumeric(TextBox9.Text) Then
        TextBox12.Text = Hex(TextBox9.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    buttonTwoPush = True
    buttonOnePush = False

    Me.Close()
    Form1.Close()

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) to issue that command at one second intervals.  Drag a Timer over to your form from the toolbox, and double click on it to get a `_Tick` method.

Set the `.Interval` member of the timer in your form's constructor, and use the `.Start` and `.Stop` methods to control it.

For the Excel piece, you'll need to add a reference to the project for the Microsoft Excel 12.0 (or 14.0 if you have Excel 2010) Object Library.  Find this under the COM tab of the `Add Reference` dialog which you get by right clicking on the project in the Solution Explorer.  See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for an exhaustive reference (scroll down to the bottom of the page for a quick example in VB.NET).